# Can not get to ect directory in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

For the life of me I can not get to the /ect directory after doing a new FreeBSD 8.2 i386 version. Basically if I type cd / and then do an ls I can see it but if i try cd /ect this does not work from either # or #/ . I am trying to edit the ip configuration file by doing vi /ect/rc.conf but I just get an empty file every time i try that and no capacity to save because it says the directory doesn't exsist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean `/etc`, do you?

(I was just guessing because you misspelled it three times)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was banging my head against the wall because the universe no longer made sense!

Comment: @Al You don't know how many times I've tried to `cd` to nonexisting folders. If you type `cd /e` and then press *Tab*, it should however autocomplete for you :)